# Como introducir datos a tablas multirelacionadas

Tags: sql-server

Tal vez el título no esté bien formulado, pero mi duda es esta, la maestra puso relacionar estas tablas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al momento de introducir valores debo meter datos que obviamente aún no tengo porque todo entra en un círculo vicioso en donde no puedo(o no sé) empezar por ningún lado. ¿cual sería la mejor manera de hacerlo? ¿introducir los

> ALTER TABLE MATERIA ADD DNI_ALUMNOS INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ALUMNO

después de ya introducir valores?

Comment: Que enredo tu pregunta, pero si lo que quieres hacer es registrar datos es muy fácil en esas tablas, aunque creo que ni sabes lo que quieres hacer. ¿Que es lo que quieres hacer? lo que resaltas es una alteración de la tabla (adición de una clave foránea relacionando 2 tablas) eso no es introducir datos. Aclara tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aunque tu pregunta es un poco enrevesada creo que entiendo tu problema. El problema que tienes es que estás relacionando tablas maestras con tablas de detalle. Me explico, la tabla alumnos, es una tabla de detalle y la tabla materia es una tabla maestra (al igual que la tabla carrera). Si haces la relación directamente tendrías que repetir registros en las tablas de carrereas y materias. Para hacer estos las relaciones deberían ser (creo que no me he dejado ninguna):

- MATERIA->CARRERA
- MATERIA->DOCENTE
- ALUMNOS<->RELMATERIAALUMNO<->MATERIA (porque un alumno puede tener más de una materia)

Los alumnos no los tienes que relacionar con los docentes porque se relacionan por materia, ya que un alumno tendrá más de una materia y, por lo tanto, más de un docente.

Es más fácil si lo piensas de manera natural y luego lo trasladas a tablas que si te intentas pelear directamente con tablas.

Ha quedado un poco largo pero espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptualmente las 4 entidades o tablas, son maestras, y no están relacionadas entre sí directamente. Las relaciones empiezan a verse mediante tablas "detalle"

Por ejemplo:

- Un Carrera tiene varias materias, una misma materia puede repetirse en varias carreras, cada materia según la carrera tiene un docente. Entonces bien podríamos tener un detalle que sea: CarrerasMateriasDocentes, con el Id de Carrera, los de cada Materia (1-N), y los del docente para la materia / carrera (1-1).
- Un alumno eventualmente podría seguir más de una carrera, por lo que ahí tendríamos una tabla AlumnosCarreras

Con estas dos tablas detalle creo que manejamos todas las relaciones de este modelo